# How to set random image in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I would like to randomly show 5 different images in basic table view cells. I am using dynamic cells. Anyone have idea how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Break the problem down. Post what you have tried.

Comment: Create array of images, and in cell for row at indexpath method get image from the array, if You want to get random image, generate a random number and use that as  index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an array with your image names:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png",@"4.png",@"5.png",nil];
```

Next in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
int random = arc4random() % array.count;
cell.imageView.image = [UImage imageWithName:[array objectAtIndex:random]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem! Have a very nice day, sir!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a cell
2. Generate random number from 1 to 5
3. Retrieve image with this index and insert into cell
4. Return cell

Jokes aside, your question is way too generic. You need to show us what have you tried and where exactly you got stuck.